# List Oracle LDAP connection endpoints for use in SQuirreL

Tags: oracle, jdbc, ldap, sqlplus, squirrel-sql

Toad/Oracle has a mechanism where it can use LDAP to lookup a list of database endpoints. It uses a file called `ldap.ora` which looks like:

```
DIRECTORY_SERVERS= (server1.foo.bar.baz:1628:1629, server2.foo.bar.baz:1628:1629)
DEFAULT_ADMIN_CONTEXT = "dc=foo,dc=bar,dc=baz"
DIRECTORY_SERVER_TYPE = OID
```

I'd like to somehow invoke the LDAP lookup and export the list of database endpoints (including server, port, etc.) so that I can connect via JDBC/SQuirreL.

1. Is there a way that I can generate the list of database endpoints given the LDAP servers?
2. Or better yet is there some oracle / SQuirreL integration that does the LDAP lookup?

*** Update ***

I originally thought I needed the server/port for each database server to formulate a JDBC url. I have now found that I can connect to a database through the ldap directory server using a connection url like:

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:@ldap://server1.foo.bar.baz:1628/XXXX,cn=OracleContext,dc=foo,dc=bar,dc=baz
```

Where XXXX is the `SID` of a database. So, it now seems that all I need is a list of `SID's`. I'm hoping that I can do this in `sqlplus`.

Comment: Well, you query LDAP for the data. (Do not know how SQuirreL can do this)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can query LDAP for the data. (Do not know how SQuirreL can do this unless you modify the code).

You need to query your LDAP for (objectclass=orclDBServer) and the data you are looking for is in the attribute orclnetdescstring and will look some thing like:

```
orclnetdescstring: (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=ordb0001.yourdomain.com)(PORT=1523))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=db.iss.com)))
```

-jim

Comment: I'm not that familiar with LDAP. Can I perform this query using the tools I have installed (browser, oracle client, sqlplus, java, unix command line)? Or do I require extra software?

Comment: Suser. ldapsearch is usually on Linux. There are several good LDAP Browsers. Apache Directory Studio is my current favorite. Something like: ldapsearch -H ldap://yourldapserver.yourdomain.com:389 -b "dc=yourldapcontext,dc=net" -s sub -a always -z 1000 "(objectclass=orclDBServer)" "orclnetdescstring"